# Increase the android app build time after the profiling

Tags: android, build, gradlew

Is there a way to speed up the build time for Android. The following is the profile report when I run `./gradlew --profile --offline --rerun-tasks assembleDevDebug`.

Apparently the core:mergeDebugNativeLibs takes the most of the time. But Realm is the only thing I am using NDK. Thanks!

```
:core   48.455s (total)
:core:mergeDebugNativeLibs  39.842s 
:core:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin  4.151s  
:core:kaptDebugKotlin   1.335s  
:core:compileDebugKotlin    1.053s  
:core:generateDebugRFile    0.899s  
:core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 0.534s  
:core:processDebugManifest  0.181s  
:core:bundleLibRuntimeDebug 0.147s  
:core:parseDebugLibraryResources    0.105s  
:core:bundleLibCompileDebug 0.033s  
:core:packageDebugResources 0.032s  
:core:javaPreCompileDebug   0.022s
```